# Call Dword into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C++ DLL file. I am facing a problem while trying to access the below mentioned function into my C# code.

```
DLLFILEACCESS_API long APIENTRY DllFAOpenFile(LPCWSTR path, DWORD* handle);
```

My revised not working C# code:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files\Yokogawa Electric Corporation\DllGXFileAccess R2.01.01\DllGXFileAccess.dll", EntryPoint = "DllGXFAOpenFile", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public static extern int FILE_OPEN([param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path, [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint handle);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long ret;
        string path = textBox1.Text;

        uint handle =0;
        //IntPtr uhandle = new IntPtr(handle);
        ret = FILE_OPEN(path, out handle);
        textBox2.Text = ret.ToString();

    }
```

I am able to marshal LPCWSTR. But i cannot marshal DWORD *handle. What is the problem here?

Comment: am getting systemviolation error at this line ret =  GXFILE_OPEN(path,handle);

Comment: "Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt” this is the complete error message

Comment: C++ `long` is 4 bytes long, even in 64-bit mode. It's I4, not I8. Also, don't comment, edit the question instead. How is `handle` initialized inside the function? Is it a DWORD pointer or a DWORD array pointer?

Comment: ok. it's a DWORD pointer. also handle is simply defined as a DWORD* handle and it's not initialised to any value. i have changed it to I4 but it's throwing me an error "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int64/UInt64 must be paired with I8 or U8)."

Comment: C++ `long` corresponds to C# `int`. C# long *is* 64 bits. As for the handle parameter, declare it as `out uint`.

Comment: Posted the modified code.Gives me output as 1. still not able to get the correct value. i should be getting '0'. Do i need to make any changes in the code?

Comment: Can you observe it on the C++ side? Maybe it's really 1. Maybe file handle 0 is already used.

Comment: This is on the C# side. That's in the header(.h) file                                 // Error Code
#define DLLFA_ERR_Success   (0x00000000)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Open    (0x00000001)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Read    (0x00000002)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Seek    (0x00000003)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Version    (0x00000004)
#define DLLFA_ERR_NotReady   (0x00000005)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Index    (0x00000006)
#define DLLFA_ERR_Unknown   (0xFFFFFFFF)

Comment: sorry the above is on c++ side. mistakenly typed

Comment: Then it's not a marshaling error anymore, it's a file open error. Can you do the same from a C++ client?

Comment: so foolish of me. it was just a file path problem. i was thinking too deep. anyway the problem is solved and thanks for your help...

Comment: In that case, let me make an answer with key steps so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this,

```
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out uint handle
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ `long` is 4 bytes long, even in 64-bit mode. It's I4, not I8. C++ `long` corresponds to C# `int`. C# `long` is 64 bits.

As for the handle parameter, declare it as `out uint`.